# Calculate the value of $\sum_{(x,y,z) \in S} g(x,y,z).$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, jordan-normal-form, jordan-algebras

Let S be a triplet set of integers $(x, y, z)$ satisfying the equation $∣x∣ + ∣y∣ + ∣z∣ = 2021$. If we define $g (x, y, z) = x + y + z$ for every real number $x, y$, and $z$,
calculate the value of $\sum_{(x,y,z) \in S}  g(x,y,z).$

Previously I have looked for the x y and z values but the results do not match, is this problem using number theory?

Comment: Hint:  If $(x,y,z)$ is a good triple then so is $(-x,-y,-z)$.

Comment: then, what should I do and use what means?

Comment: I've given you a strong hint.  Try working with it.  If you are having trouble getting started, try it for a smaller number than $2021$.

Comment: Try working with the hint.  Take more than a couple of minutes.  Examples are an excellent way to proceed.  Instead of $2021$, suppose we had $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$.  Can you do it then?  What about $|x|+|y|+|z|=2$?  And so on.

Comment: So far I've tried, but I can't find it and I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MASSIVE HINT

@Lulu has pointed out that solutions occur in pairs $(x,y,z)$ and $(-x,-y,-z)$.

Consider for example the pair of solutions $(3,-4,2014)$ and  $(-3,4,-2014)$. What is the value of $(3-4+2014)+(-3+4-2014)$?

Do you now see what the point of the hint was?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank u, now i know

Comment: Great. It's a clever idea isn't it.

Comment: yeah, that's right. Thank u very much :), and now I have the answer